# Error while capturing photo (NullPointerException in LinearLayout)

Tags: android, android-camera

I am capturing photo in my application using Intent:

```
Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST);
```

but when I capture the photo and click on Save button then it throw error which is:

```
liblog              failed to call dumpstate
AndroidRuntime      java.lang.NullPointerException
AndroidRuntime      at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutHorizontal(LinearLayout.java:1210)
AndroidRuntime      at android.widget.TableRow.onLayout(TableRow.java:121)       
AndroidRuntime      at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7175)
AndroidRuntime      at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1254)
AndroidRuntime      at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1130)
AndroidRuntime      at android.widget.TableLayout.onLayout(TableLayout.java:440)
AndroidRuntime      at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7175)
AndroidRuntime      at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:338)
AndroidRuntime      at android.widget.ScrollView.onLayout(ScrollView.java:1565)
AndroidRuntime      at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7175)
AndroidRuntime      at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1254)
AndroidRuntime      at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1130)
AndroidRuntime      at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(Lin1earLayout.java:1047)
AndroidRuntime      at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7175)
AndroidRuntime      at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:338)
AndroidRuntime      at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7175)
AndroidRuntime      at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1254)
AndroidRuntime      at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1130)
AndroidRuntime      at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1047)
AndroidRuntime      at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7175)
AndroidRuntime      at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:338)
AndroidRuntime      at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7175)
AndroidRuntime      at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:1146)
AndroidRuntime      at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1865)
AndroidRuntime      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
AndroidRuntime      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)     
AndroidRuntime      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
AndroidRuntime      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)          
AndroidRuntime      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)       
AndroidRuntime      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
AndroidRuntime      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625)
AndroidRuntime      at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                    Dumpstate > /data/log/dumpstate_app_error
```

but when I use this application into different mobile then it work perfectly.
I don't know what is the problem.

Code after capturing photo:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    try {
        if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST) {

            Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
            imageViewPhoto.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

        }

    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Problem while capturing photo. Try after some time.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: I have edited my question and I mention code after capturing photo.
Here this code is not exact code buy similar to this.

Comment: Maybe the user quit the app without taking a photo?

Comment: did you use setResult(int resultCode);  ???

Comment: @rekire no dear after capturing photo when I click on Save button then it throwing error. But when I use this application in different mobile then it not throwing any error

Comment: @Hulk No I not use any setResult(int resultCode). Where and how to use this?

Comment: after capturing image, on the save button you can set code like setResult(21);
So that when your cursor come into onActivityResult(), you can also check the resultCode like you are doing with requestCode
like--
if(resultCode ==21){//do whatever your code needed}

Comment: @Hulk But Save button is internal button of intent. how I write code there??

Comment: I guess the problem is with this line           \  Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");                                       let me know  if you get nullpointer on this line             imageViewPhoto.setImageBitmap(bitmap);